# Prove $\cos(x)<\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I have to prove that $\cos(x)<\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}$ for $0<x<\frac\pi2$. By using the MVT I got that $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}=\cos^2(c)>\cos^2(x)$ for a $c\in[0, x]$ but this doesn't help since $\cos^2(x)<\cos(x)$ because $0<\cos x<1$.

The derivative didnt help either, since the derivatives of both $\cos(x)x^2-\sin^2(x)$ and $\cos(x)-\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}$ don't have roots that I can easily find/I don't see a way to prove that they don't have roots.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1463208p8456274

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $\sin(x)\tan(x) > x^2$ for $x \in ( \,0, \frac{\pi}{2}) \,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132507/prove-sinx-tanx-x2-for-x-in-0-frac-pi2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step I: $x^{3} >2(x-\sin x)$. To prove this note that the left side vanishes at $0$ and the derivative is positive: Recall that $\cos x >1-\frac {x^{2}}2$.

Step II: Use $tanx >x$ to get $x^{2} \tan x > 2(x-\sin x)$. With this you can easily check that the derivative of $x^{2}\cos x-\sin ^{2}x$ is negative which gives $x^{2}\cos x-\sin ^{2}x<0$.

Comment: @wolfuryo I have not not used series expansion.  The fact that $\cos x >1-\frac {x^{2}} 2$ can be cheked by differentiation.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

The statement is equivalent to
$$
x\cot x < \frac{{\sin x}}{x}
$$
for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Now
$$
x\cot x = 1 - \frac{{x^2 }}{3} -  \cdots \leq 1 - \frac{{x^2 }}{3}, \quad (|x|<\pi)
$$
since all the Taylor coefficients except for the first one are negative. It is well known that
$$
\frac{{\sin x}}{x} > 1 - \frac{{x^2 }}{6}
$$
for all real $x\neq 0$. Since $$
1 - \frac{{x^2 }}{6} > 1 - \frac{{x^2 }}{3}
$$
for positive $x$, the proof is complete. This derivation shows that the claim is actually true for $0<x<\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I'm not supposed to use series expansions here. I should have mentioned that in my question.